# Trying to use Preferences in java but need admin rights (need to work on windows and MAC)

Tags: java, windows, macos, preferences

I am trying to save some settings for my program.

I am for instance asking the user to pick a folder
when the program is run for the first time.

this is all working and wonderfull, but it does not get saved.

`prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());`

Returns with `WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.`

error code 5 (access denied)

How do i ask for admin rights? both on windows and mac, thank you for your time!

Comment: ask means .. programmatically or ?

Comment: I actually found out when using userRoot(), that the program indeed makes the key.

It just throws a warning because java tries to make it in systemRoot() too, incase
you ever need it in systemroot, but since you are using userRoot() you never will.

Comment: @user1428716 Yes, ask the user to either log in or to accept that the program has admin rights. Do you know a way for further referance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found out when using userRoot(), that the program indeed makes the key. It just throws a warning because java tries to make it in systemRoot() aswell, just incase you ever need it in systemroot. When you are using userRoot() you never will.